# hyperref, how to make 'pdfborder' larger, or add some margin between the border and the text

Tags: spacing, hyperref

Using the `hyperref` package, is there a way to make the border around the link or whatever larger so that it is not tightly sticked to the text? Like adding some margin between the text and the box around it?

Comment: If you don't get an answer you can ask the question at [comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/topics?hl=en). The maintainer of packages `hyperref` is very active in this newsgroup.

Comment: Should the border push the adjacent text and stuff away or cut through it?

Comment: @Andy push away

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure what are are trying to accomplish. In principle, you can get that behavior with `\marginbox` from the `adjustbox` package. I made a small example for a hyperlink that shows the described feature.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pdfborder={1 1 1},pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\begin{document}
Foo \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32994/hyperref-how-to-make-pdfborder-larger-or-add-some-margin-between-the-border}{\marginbox{2pt}{bar}} what?
\end{document}
```

[image: example link]

If all links should automatically have that behavior, some more work is necessary.

Comment: i want to do exactly what you have done, but i do not know how to use this workaround for things like \ref{01.fig}

Comment: @runnerup: Do you *only* want this to be done for things like `\ref{...}`?

Comment: @Werner for _some_ documents, yes